# Dual clock FIFO in vivado (verilog)

Tags: fpga, fifo, vivado

I want to use a FIFO in a project where a state machine buffers as much data as possible to a FIFO, which will then be processed by a DSP block. To maximize data throughput I want to use multiple QSPI nor flash modules as a ROM with a wide data bus. DSP blocks can perform 1 operation per cycle which means the data input width has to be larger than the output width (because it takes 8 clock cycles to transfer data). For example, I want a FIFO with 32-bit input and 8-bit output, but this is not supported in vivado as far as I can tell. I tried the various FIFO block generators and even tried using the macros but I'm not having much luck.

Please let me know how I can generate a dual clock FIFO with a larger input width than the output width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FIFO Generator IP core in Vivado, choose `Independent Clocks Block RAM` for FIFO Implementation and then you will be able to set larger data width for write port than the read port.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is exactly the opposite of what I want to do. I want a wider read port. Again let's assume it takes 8 cycles to load 1 byte and the DSP can process 1 byte per clock cycle. That means there are 7 wasted cycles, but if we load 8 bytes using a larger read port, there are no wasted cycles, and data is processed as a continuous stream.

Comment: @OM222O You said " I want a FIFO with 32-bit input and 8-bit output". FIFO inputs are write port and FIFO outputs are read port. So your question should be a FIFO with larger input port than output port which is still possible with the same method.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that! I was reading that at 2 AM and my brain wasn't working!